# How to use CSS Style one class inside another class but another class don't affect main class style

Tags: html, css

I used two classes `.swap` and `.cont`. How to use `.swap` class style so that it won't effect `.cont` style.

```css
.swap{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px ;
}

.cont{
  margin-top: 10em;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="swap">
   <div class="cont">
        <div class="container">test</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There a css error in your code.. after padding you should add `:` selector like this `padding:10px 10px 10px 10px ;`

Comment: Which styles should be applied to the `.swap`-div and which should not be applied to the `.cont`-div?

Answer (score 1):

using :not css

```
:not(X) {
  property: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `:not(nameOfSelector)` css rule, as stated by Prajapati Ghanshyam who posted it first, or, even simpler and safer (for older browser compatibility's sake), you can override the css rules previously set by `.swap` by doing:

```
<style>
.swap{
background-color:red;
padding 10px 10px 10px 10px ;
}

.cont{
margin-top: 10em;
color: blue;
/* OVERRIDE */
background-color: #acolorofyourchoice;
padding: 0;
/* END OVERRIDE */
}
</style>
```

Comment: [Does not work](https://jsfiddle.net/oL4qL86v/) because the initial / transparent takes the parent div color or will overlay the color with "nothing", you still see red..